# How to remove Save Log Error in MongoDB for $pull/$set operators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get this annoying save log error in mongodb while using operators like $pull or $set in my update operations.

```
SaveLogError: Error: key $pull must not start with '$'
```

Although the operation actually does complete successfully, this annoying error clutters my log files.

I am using Mongoose 4.13.0 in Node.js app and my MongoDB version 3.6

Here is a sample query where is get this error:

```
Student.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:studentId },{ $pull: {'studentResults' : {'_id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(resultId)} }}, callback)
```

I have tried putting the $pull in double quotes ("$pull") but no luck.

Comment: Did you look into this and other results that pop up in google? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1884

Comment: @Akrion I did actually have a look into this thread. Updating the driver works for these guys but this a very old conversation. I have a higher version of both mongoDB and mongoose

Comment: Update mongoose version to **5.x** might help you!!!